# V-Ray .exr to mp4 ffmpeg Stuttering

Tags: video, ffmpeg, openexr

I have an issue using ffmpeg with V-Ray exr.

I'm trying to export .mp4 from .exr, so ihave used this command

> ffmpeg.exe -y -start_number 1 -framerate 25 -i D:\temp\WAC_TEST\what_about_cooking_sq01_p040_rendering_main_publish_v000.%4d.exr -pix_fmt gbrapf32le D:/out_vray_exr.mp4

I have verified parameters using

> ffmpeg.exe -y -start_number 1 -i D:\temp\WAC_TEST\what_about_cooking_sq01_p040_rendering_main_publish_v000.%4d.exr

Result :

> Input #0, image2, from Input #0, image2, from 'D:\temp\WAC_TEST\what_about_cooking_sq01_p040_rendering_main_publish_v000.%4d.exr':
> Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0: Video: exr, gbrapf32le, 2840x1210 [SAR 1:1 DAR 284:121], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn

Finally, Exported video are unreadable by windows player and KMplayer
[image]

I can play the video using VLC. but i got stuttering frame like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8MawpkKGfc

To understand this behaviour i have export .exr sequence to .png and i got this
[image]

I also tried this command with a simple cube animation using mantra on Houdini, it's just work perfectly, but if i export this cube animation using vray, i got stuterring frame and this strange behaviour.

Thank you.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PsHTW4R9 @Gyan

Comment: There are a lot of warnings about unsupported channels although that may not be the core problem. The H.264 profile selected is `High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 5.0, 4:4:4, 10-bit` which is not widely compatible. Use `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.  Floating point RGBA is not happening with H.264.

Comment: Thank you for your help,
I have tried using -pix_fmt yuv420p but same problem, do you want the report to?

Comment: Make sure your images are numbered smoothly with no gaps and with a fixed field i.e. `0008, 0009, 0010` and not `8,9,10`

Comment: The name of one exr for example is what_about_cooking_sq01_p040_rendering_main_publish_v000.0001.exr
There is no gap between file. When i test these .exr on Nuke for example, everything is smooth.
If you want i  can share you the .exr sequences if you want to test locally.

Comment: Ok. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you again, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yvotF6sTEFeRQ4shUx63Rz6UEdmK7WzN?usp=sharing

Comment: The stuttering appears to be part of the source, as I see it when playing the exrs in djv

Comment: So weird because for me stuttering doesn't appear in djv (2.0.8).
But i think it's a problem with vray maybe, because if i export just a spinning cube i have the same result, but with mantra it's work smoothly.